# Polymer 2 update paper-listbox item

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a collection of objects which have a `name` property.
For editing these objects I have a paper-listbox that lists the names of the objects and lets the user select one of the objects by name. Next to the listbox I have a form with paper-inputs etc to edit properties of the selected object. One of the paper-inputs binds to the name property of the selected object so the user can change the name.

My problem is that the changes to the name property are not reflected to the listbox. How do I update the listbox after the user has changed the name?

I confirmed that the name change actually happens because when I change to another object and back to the previous one the changed name is still there.
The problem is just that the listbox does not update.

I tried something like:

```
this.notifyPath("myObjects")
```

but that doesn't do anything.

The paper-listbox is created like this

```
<paper-listbox selected="{{selectedObjectIndex}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myObjects]]">
        <paper-item>[[item.name]]</paper-item>
    </template>
</paper-listbox>
```

`selectedObjectIndex` has an observer that sets the selected object

```
selectedPageIndexChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    ...
    this.selectedObject = this.myObjects[this.selectedObjectIndex];
}
```

Comment: have you tried this.notifyPath(myObjects.selectedObjectIndex.name)  ?

Comment: @vals thanks, that indeed works, the correct syntax would be this.notifyPath("myObjects." + this.selectedObjectIndex + ".name"). See my comment to HakanCs answer for the final solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here below some working and not working examples. (I tried to illustrate the code at codepen as show [DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/wRmRaO?editors=1011), here also part of the code in order to quick inspection.

```
 <paper-listbox selected="{{selectedObjectIndex}}">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myObjects}}" >
    <paper-item>[[index]].[[item.name]]</paper-item> <br/>
  </template>
 </paper-listbox>
 <paper-input value="{{selectedObject.name}}" ></paper-input>
```

....

```
     selectedObjectIndex:{
           type:Number,
           observer:'selectedPageIndexChanged'
         }
      }} 
      static get observers() {return ['nameValueChanged(selectedObject.name)']}
      constructor() {
            super();
       }

       ready() {
            super.ready();

        }

  selectedPageIndexChanged(newValue, oldValue) {

      this.selectedObject = this.myObjects[newValue];
  }
 nameValueChanged(name){
      //this.myObjects[this.selectedObjectIndex].name = name;
      //this.set('myObjects.' + this.selectedObjectIndex + ".name", name ) // --> Does not work
      this.set('myObjects.' + this.selectedObjectIndex, { name: name} ) // --> Works
      // this.splice('myObjects', this.selectedObjectIndex,1, this.selectedObject) -- Does not work

      //this.notifyPath('myObjects.' + this.selectedObjectIndex + ".name") // -- works (with one of above)

 }
}
```

The above  signed `Does not work` lines changes the object but not observable at `dom-repeat`

Comment: thanks for this detailed example and showing non working snippets too. The comment by vals already fixes it BUT your solution opens up the possibility to get rid of my "Save" button. It turns out there is no need to have a save button when the paper-input is bound to "selectedObject.name" because your use  of the "nameValueChanged" observer then allows me to update the list box while I'm typing and I also don't need to create an entirely new object instance in nameValueChanged. Just the call to this.notifyPath in nameValueChanged is then necessary. Great user experience :-)